# How do I switch out a DropDownList with True and False and Not Set with a CheckBox in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I'm new to mvc and was wondering if there was a way to switch out a DropDownList with a CheckBox. 
In my database I've got a property with a datatype of bit. In Visual Studios, after I create my model and controller and run it, it shows up as a DropDownList with True and False. I'd like this to be just a Checkbox instead of a DropDownList for both the Index and the Create views. I also (obviously) need it to bind to the database after creating a new item. I'm sure there is a way to achieve this, I just haven't been able to find the answer. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm assuming you using `@Html.EditorFor()` for the property. By default a `bool` property will be shown as a checkbox. Perhaps you have a nullable bool, it witch case it will a dropdown, but with 3 values (True, False and Not Set). You need to give a bit more information including the model and the view.

Comment: Stephen, originally it was a nullable bool because I added the columns after my tables already had data in them. After editing those tables, I forgot to go back and make them non-nullable. Then I forgot I had to refresh my edmx. But I eventually remembered and now it works! Thanks for (kinda) answering my question :)

Comment: So the question is not left unanswered, you can add your own answer and accept it (but edit the question to say _as a DropDownList with True and False and Not Set_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen pretty much answered my question with his comment. By default, a bool property will be shown as a checkbox. But since I had added the columns after the table already had data in them, the only way was to make them nullable. After going back and putting values into the tables for the new columns, I was able to go back and make the new columns non-nullable. After refreshing my edmx, they showed up as checkboxes!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, as long as your database column is being mapped to a boolean property, i.e.:

```
public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeBoolean)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the help!